# Fatal error C1083 installing ursa

Tags: node.js

I got the following error installing URSA on node.js (I'm using windows 7).

```
c:\users\napoleon\node_modules\ursa\src\ursaNative.h(10): fatal error C1083: Ca
nnot open include file: 'openssl/rsa.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\Na
poleon\node_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
```

I have tried (reading on the internet it seems the problem has to do with SDK or OpenSSL):

- Reinstalling Windows SDK 7
- Upgraded to the newer version 7.1.
- Reinstalled OpenSSl 1.0.1h 64.
- Removed the previous and installed OpenSSl 1.0.0 m (I have no idea what the m, h mean).

I have a few different versions of the redistributable Microsoft visual C++.

No idea what to try, any help is appreciated.

Edit: I checked the path and indeed it seems there isn't a file there. However it's supposed to be intalled BY ursa as far as I see, so the problem is probably ursa failing to install this.

Edit 2: I watched the folder while trying to install, a URSA folder appears and disappears with the error, so it's definitely a problem installing the file, anyone what can cause that.

Comment: Did you put OpenSSL in the default install directory (C:\OpenSSL-Win32 or C:\OpenSSL-Win64)?

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley Yes I did

Comment: You need to add the openssl include directory to the default VC++ include paths.

Comment: @ChrisTavares sweet someone knows what the solution is, I don't understand what you're saying though, can you guide me through it?

Answer (score 0):

After you install the openSSL library, VC++ needs to know how to find the include files when building stuff. That's not set up by default.

VC++ uses the INCLUDE environment variable as part of it's include file search path. So before you run the npm install, do this from the command line:

```
set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;<PATH TO OPENSSL INCLUDES GOES HERE>
```

Basically whatever the parent directory of openssl/rsa.h is, put that in the include path.

Comment: Did it wrong:
http://puu.sh/a7fKJ/50d6ea08e7.png
Likely that I made tons of mistakes (I'm just unsure which CMD you mean and hoping I typed it correctly). Baby steps for dumb please? (Not marking as accepted answer since I'd really like it to work before I do).

Comment: You almost got it right - don't include the <> characters.

Comment: Oh, and the "CMD" I was talking about was the same command prompt you would be typing "npm install ursa" into.

Comment: There's where I type npm install ursa :P. I'll try this without the <> and if it doesn't work will try the node CMD (assuming that's what you meant).

Comment: Didn't solve the problem or I did it wrong:
http://puu.sh/a7Z2F/bba36abf6f.png
| http://puu.sh/a7Z3G/7646f00e99.png
|http://puu.sh/a7Z4Q/d5f6417623.png
I tried the above^, opened a new CMD and tried installing again, same error.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded the openssl library and checked out the path. Do `set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\OpenSSL-Win64\include` to get the right path set. Also, be sure you're running the 64-bit version of node if you're using the 64-bit version of openssl.

Comment: Darn still failing, I'm trying to install: https://github.com/Medium/ursa
Is there a specific version of SSL (does it matter?), because I installed the 1.0.1h normal 64 one. - http://puu.sh/a8Apq/e7772037b4.png

Comment: Sorry, I'm done, I can't debug a build for a project I don't know.

Comment: Uhh progress! After reinstalling I get the following error:
http://puu.sh/a9mF1/21345a2410.png (hopefully this is a error that occurs after the previous one and not because i installed something incorrectly). Do you have any idea how to order the errors, as in have I worsened the situation or improved it haha.

Comment: I have a few questions which I'd rather ask you in chat as to not to spam, I don't have reputation to invite to a chatroom, if you agree could you create one?

Comment: To be specific, I believe I didn't install all the compenonets of VC++ correctly, and I do not know (it isn't specified) which are needed, also I just found out there is a Microsoft visual studio CMD, which I assume that it was there I needed to set the path, basically I messed up bad D:

Comment: Mr.Tavares I believe I got over that problem (I believe) and now getting this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805721/npm-install-ursa-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-c-microsoft-cpp-default. Do you happen to know any solution?